# how to create backup of my database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to create back of my database which is made in SQL Server Express edition?

I want to create backup and restore it how could this do 
please tell me

Comment: **@user547534** : Accept the answers of question you had asked earlier. It would encourages others to answers your question.

Comment: Option 1: Put "backup and restore sql server" in to Goolge. Option 2: Ask this question on http://serverfault.com/. Even if you do neither, at least accept the answers to your other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [BACKUP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) command.

For example:

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
TO DISK='Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdvWorksData.bak' 
WITH FORMAT
```